# Could the structure with "preposition + adjective " be possible?

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs

i am looking at the sentence, "The bird will fit in just fine ". I think that the structure of the sentence has "preposition + adjective " . [ in(preposition) + fine ( adjective) ]

Could the structure with "preposition + adjective " be possible ?

what does "The bird will fit in just fine " mean ?
 does it mean "The bird will fit in just being fine" ?

Comment: MorganFR// does "fit in" mean " a verb" ? therefore, Could the adjective of fine after a verb (fit in) be possible ?

Comment: "To fit in" is a phrasal verb. It follows the same rules as most other verbs. In your case, "fine" is an adverb, which is usually what follows a verb. If you wanna know if what follows is an adjective or an adverb, try to use "good." The adjective for "good" is "good", and the adverb is "well." In your sentence, the bird can fit in well, not good. Another method would be to check if you use the adjective, or the adverb that is made by using "ly" at the end of it. E.g. "The bird will fit in nicely (not nice)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In" is just part of the phrasal verb "to fit in" - to be socially compatible with other members of a group. [Here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/phrasal-verbs)'s some info about phrasal verbs. Verbs, as such, can be followed by adverbs for instance.

In the case of your sentence, "just fine" is made out of the words "fine," which here is an adverb modifying "fit in," and the adverb "just" modifying "fine."

Adjectives modify nouns and pronouns, while adverbs modify verbs, adjectives or other adverbs.

If you wanna know if what follows is an adjective or an adverb, try to either use the word "good" whose adverb is "well", or an adjective like "nice," because if you add "-ly" to nice, it becomes the adverb "nicely".

In your example, you will say "The bird will fit in well/nicely/just fine," therefore "fine" is an adverb.

[Here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/adjAdv.asp)'s some more information about adjectives and adverbs.

Comment: Right -- but you might include your observation about *fine* being an adverb modifying the verb (or the clause), since that is what OP asks about, and add that *just* is an adverb modifying *fine*.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, I will add some of that information, I was just writing that as a comment following the OP's comment.